# error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Grafico

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Soy relativamente nuevo en programación en android con Android Studio y estaba haciendo el [tutorial](http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android/35-unidad-4-graficos-en-android/138-creando-la-actividad-principal-de-asteroides) que muestro en el enlace.

Sin embargo me quedé trabado ya que me da error cuando hago el siguiente bucle for:

```
for (Grafico asteroide: Asteroides) {
        asteroide.dibujaGrafico(canvas);
    }
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Grafico

¿Alguien sabe por qué no me permite recorrer ese vector de datos tipo "Grafico"?

El código completo del programa es el siguiente:

```
package asteroides.example.org.asteroides;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Vector;


/**
 * Created by usuario on 18/04/2017.
 */

public class VistaJuego extends View {
    // //// ASTEROIDES //////
    private Vector Asteroides; // Vector con los Asteroides
    private int numAsteroides= 5; // Número inicial de asteroides
    private int numFragmentos= 3; // Fragmentos en que se divide
    private Grafico asteroide;
    public VistaJuego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Drawable drawableNave, drawableAsteroide, drawableMisil;
        drawableAsteroide = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.asteroide1);
        Asteroides = new Vector();
        for (int i = 0; i < numAsteroides; i++) {
            asteroide = new Grafico(this, drawableAsteroide);
            asteroide.setIncY(Math.random() * 4 - 2);
            asteroide.setIncX(Math.random() * 4 - 2);
            asteroide.setAngulo((int) (Math.random() * 360));
            asteroide.setRotacion((int) (Math.random() * 8 - 4));
            Asteroides.add(asteroide);
        }
    }
    @Override protected void onSizeChanged(int ancho, int alto,
                                           int ancho_anter, int alto_anter) {
        super.onSizeChanged(ancho, alto, ancho_anter, alto_anter);
        // Una vez que conocemos nuestro ancho y alto.
        for (Grafico asteroide: Asteroides) {
            asteroide.setPosX(Math.random()*
                    (ancho-asteroide.getAncho()));
            asteroide.setPosY(Math.random()*
                    (alto-asteroide.getAlto()));
        }
    }
    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (Grafico asteroide: Asteroides) {
            asteroide.dibujaGrafico(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Y la clase **`Grafico`** es la siguiente:

```
public class Grafico {
    public Drawable getDrawable() {
        return drawable;
    }

    public void setDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    public double getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }

    public void setPosX(double posX) {
        this.posX = posX;
    }

    public double getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }

    public void setPosY(double posY) {
        this.posY = posY;
    }

    public double getIncX() {
        return incX;
    }

    public void setIncX(double incX) {
        this.incX = incX;
    }

    public double getIncY() {
        return incY;
    }

    public void setIncY(double incY) {
        this.incY = incY;
    }

    public int getAngulo() {
        return angulo;
    }

    public void setAngulo(int angulo) {
        this.angulo = angulo;
    }

    public int getRotacion() {
        return rotacion;
    }

    public void setRotacion(int rotacion) {
        this.rotacion = rotacion;
    }

    public int getAncho() {
        return ancho;
    }

    public void setAncho(int ancho) {
        this.ancho = ancho;
    }

    public int getAlto() {
        return alto;
    }

    public void setAlto(int alto) {
        this.alto = alto;
    }

    public int getRadioColision() {
        return radioColision;
    }

    public void setRadioColision(int radioColision) {
        this.radioColision = radioColision;
    }

    public View getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public static int getMaxVelocidad() {
        return MAX_VELOCIDAD;
    }

    private Drawable drawable;   //Imagen que dibujaremos
    private double posX, posY;   //Posición
    private double incX, incY;   //Velocidad desplazamiento
    private int angulo, rotacion;//Ángulo y velocidad rotación
    private int ancho, alto;     //Dimensiones de la imagen
    private int radioColision;   //Para determinar colisión
    //Donde dibujamos el gráfico (usada en view.ivalidate)
    private View view;
    // Para determinar el espacio a borrar (view.ivalidate)
    public static final int MAX_VELOCIDAD = 20;

    public Grafico(View view, Drawable drawable){
        this.view = view;
        this.drawable = drawable;
        ancho = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        alto = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        radioColision = (alto+ancho)/4;
    }
    public void dibujaGrafico(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.save();
        int x=(int) (posX+ancho/2);
        int y=(int) (posY+alto/2);
        canvas.rotate((float) angulo,(float) x,(float) y);
        drawable.setBounds((int)posX, (int)posY,
                (int)posX+ancho, (int)posY+alto);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        int rInval = (int) Math.hypot(ancho,alto)/2 + MAX_VELOCIDAD;
        view.invalidate(x-rInval, y-rInval, x+rInval, y+rInval);
    }
    public void incrementaPos(double factor){
        posX+=incX * factor;
        // Si salimos de la pantalla, corregimos posición
        if(posX<-ancho/2) {posX=view.getWidth()-ancho/2;}
        if(posX>view.getWidth()-ancho/2) {posX=-ancho/2;}
        posY+=incY * factor;
        if(posY<-alto/2) {posY=view.getHeight()-alto/2;}
        if(posY>view.getHeight()-alto/2) {posY=-alto/2;}
        angulo += rotacion * factor; //Actualizamos ángulo
    }
    public double distancia(Grafico g) {
        return Math.hypot(posX-g.posX, posY-g.posY);
    }
    public boolean verificaColision(Grafico g) {
        return(distancia(g) < (radioColision+g.radioColision));
    }
}
```

Comment: y donde te muestra el error, que linea de LogCat de consola?

Comment: Aqui exactamente: "for (Grafico asteroide: Asteroides) {"

Comment: Tienes que cambiar a for (Object asteroide: Asteroides) {  y posteriormente castear :  asteroide = (Grafico) asteroide; @Leo_Gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando realizas esto, marca tipos incompatibles, se requiere un Object no Grafico

```
 for (Grafico asteroide: Asteroides) {
  ...
  ...
 }
```

debes cambiar a obtener cada elemento de tipo Grafico, realizando un cast dentro del Vector, y posteriormente cambiar sus propiedades :

```
  Grafico asteroide;
  for (Object asteroide: Asteroides) {
        asteroide = (Grafico) asteroide;
      ...
      ...
  }
```

Otra opción:

```
    Grafico asteroide;
    for (int i=0;i<Asteroides.size();i++) {
        asteroide = (Grafico) Asteroides.get(i);
      ...
      ...
    }
```

---

Ejemplo a):

```
 @Override protected void onSizeChanged(int ancho, int alto,
                                           int ancho_anter, int alto_anter) {
        super.onSizeChanged(ancho, alto, ancho_anter, alto_anter);
        // Una vez que conocemos nuestro ancho y alto.

      // for (Grafico asteroide: Asteroides) {
        Grafico asteroide;
      for (Object asteroide: Asteroides) {
            asteroide = (Grafico) asteroide;

            asteroide.setPosX(Math.random()*
                    (ancho-asteroide.getAncho()));
            asteroide.setPosY(Math.random()*
                    (alto-asteroide.getAlto()));
        }
    }
```

Ejemplo b)

```
 @Override protected void onSizeChanged(int ancho, int alto,
                                           int ancho_anter, int alto_anter) {
        super.onSizeChanged(ancho, alto, ancho_anter, alto_anter);
        // Una vez que conocemos nuestro ancho y alto.

      // for (Grafico asteroide: Asteroides) {
        Grafico asteroide;
        for (int i=0;i<Asteroides.size();i++) {
            asteroide = (Grafico) Asteroides.get(i);

            asteroide.setPosX(Math.random()*
                    (ancho-asteroide.getAncho()));
            asteroide.setPosY(Math.random()*
                    (alto-asteroide.getAlto()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Porque solo dan -1 y no agregan la razón?

Comment: Me funcionó Jorge, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Un placer, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Falla porque `Asteroides` es un array de la clase `Vector`, por lo que está compuesto de objetos de la clase `Vector`.
Estás intentando recorrer el array, y convertirlos a `Grafico`.

Tu bucle debería ser algo así:

```
for (Vector asteroide: Asteroides) {
    //lo que sea
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu array `Asteroides` está devolviendo `Object` en vez de objetos `Grafico`.
Haciendo un *cast*, probablemente soluciones tu error:

```
for (Object asteroide: Asteroides) {
    Grafico grf = (Grafico) asteroide;
    grf.dibujaGrafico(canvas);
}
```